# How to match '<a href=' in a string?

Tags: preg-match

Ok so I'm circling around this site and people are like "OMG, don't use regexp and html!" Well, I just have a custom field in WP that I want to match anything with a simple "a href=" and indicate that it's there.

I easily get a headache when I start reading about regexp so anyone want to give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's really that simple, you don't need a regex at all. You can do a simple [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (or [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) for case-insensitive) search to see if the string contains `"a href="`.

```
if(strpos($input, 'a href=') !== false) {
    // stuff
}
```